# Integer to a template: cannot appear in a constant-expression

Tags: c++, templates

I never did template programming. What I need is the following: depending on certain integer (user input), my template should determine a type. Here is my template:

```
template<int T> struct abcd {};

template<>
struct abcd<6> { typedef double type_t; };
template<>
struct abcd<5> { typedef float type_t; };
template<>
struct abcd<0> { typedef unsigned char type_t; };enter code here
```

In certain function I want to use my template like this:

```
void foo(int i, int m)
{
    const int j = i;
    // Assume elements of A can be accessed as A.at<dataType>(location)
    int a = A<abcd<j>::type_t>(m)
   //do something.. 
}
```

This is showing error `cannot appear in a constant-expression`. Please tell me what I am doing wrong and what can be a solution. Note that if I put `const int j = 5` or any other relevant `int` instead of `const int j = i`, it is working fine. That is confusing me.

Comment: Do you know about template instantiation? If no, read about it. If yes, think about this: How could a compiler possibly instantiate those templates?

Comment: We can hardly teach you the substantial concept of templates. You need a book.

Answer (score 2):

`abcd<j>` has to be instantiated at compile time, so `j` has to be a constant expression. In your case, you don't know `j` at compile time, since it is obtained from the parameter of the function `foo`, and that's why the error.

Parameters of a function are not considered constant expressions, even if you invoke `foo(6,...)`. The argument `6`, although known at compile time, is bounded to the parameter `i`, which is NOT by itself a constant expression.

You may have though that you have something like

```
foo(constexpr i, int m)
```

but such syntax is illegal, that is, function parameters cannot be constant expressions. I do not know exactly why the standard does not allow such constructions, and I'm more than willing to hear any opinions.

A workaround is to declare `foo` taking `i` as a template, like

```
template<int i>
void foo(int m)
{
    const int j = i;
    // now can use j as a constant expression
}
```

and invoke it as e.g.

```
f<5>(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

the value of j must be known during compilation time.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that template parameters need to be known at **compile time**. You've declared `j` as a constant, but it is not known at compile time